# I am trying to make a lcd program so that all the numbers are printed side by side and its not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print out ascii numbers side by side in python after the previous number is printed. If I put a comma after the last line in the function only the top part of the next number is printed.

```
def zero():
    print " __ "
    print "|  |"
    print "|__|"

def one():
    print "    "
    print "   |"
    print "   |"

def two():
    print " __ "
    print " __|"
    print "|__ "

def three():
    print " __ "
    print " __|"
    print " __|"

def four():
    print "|_|"
    print "  |"

def five():
    print " __ "
    print "|__ "
    print " __|"

def six():
    print " __ "
    print "|__ "
    print "|__|"

def seven():
    print "  __ "
    print "    |"
    print "    |"

def eight():
    print " __ "
    print "|__|"
    print "|__|"

def nine():
    print " __ "
    print "|__|"
    print "   |"



x = raw_input("Type the number you would like printed: ")
a = list(x)
for x in a:
    if x == '1':
        one(),
    elif x == '2':
        two(),
    elif x == '3':
        three(),
    elif x == '4':
        four(),
    elif x == '5':
        five(),
    elif x == '6':
        six(),
    elif x == '7':
        seven(),
    elif x == '8':
        eight(),
    elif x == '9':
        nine(),
    elif x == '0':
        zero(),
    elif x == 'Quit':
        break
    else:
        print "Number not entered"
```

Comment: Your approach is completely wrong. You can't print all of the lines of the display at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, your approach was a bit off.  I implemented one that takes your list numbers and then builds the result line by line (i.e., top, middle, then bottom).

```
class zero:
    top = " __ "
    mid = "|  |"
    bot = "|__|"

class one:
    top = "    "
    mid = "   |"
    bot = "   |"

class two:
    top = " __ "
    mid = " __|"
    bot = "|__ "

class three:
    top = " __ "
    mid = " __|"
    bot = " __|"

class four:
    top = "   "
    mid = "|_|"
    bot = "  |"

class five:
    top = " __ "
    mid = "|__ "
    bot = " __|"

class six:
    top = " __ "
    mid = "|__ "
    bot = "|__|"

class seven:
    top = "  __ "
    mid = "    |"
    bot = "    |"

class eight:
    top = " __ "
    mid = "|__|"
    bot = "|__|"

class nine:
    top = " __ "
    mid = "|__|"
    bot = "   |"

def printnum(list):
    chunks = ['top','mid','bot']
    for section in chunks:
        string = ''
        for x in list:
            if x == '1':
                string += getattr(one, section)
            elif x == '2':
                string += getattr(two, section)
            elif x == '3':
                string += getattr(three, section)
            elif x == '4':
                string += getattr(four, section)
            elif x == '5':
                string += getattr(five, section)
            elif x == '6':
                string += getattr(six, section)
            elif x == '7':
                string += getattr(seven, section)
            elif x == '8':
                string += getattr(eight, section)
            elif x == '9':
                string += getattr(nine, section)
            elif x == '0':
                string += getattr(zero, section)
            elif x == 'Quit':
                break
            else:
                print "Number not entered"
        print string

x = raw_input("Type the number you would like printed: ")
a = list(x)

printnum(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code prints three lines of output:

```
print " __ "
print "|__|"
print "   |"
```

One that is printed, there is no good way to go back up and print the next number.

The solution is to print the first line of each character, then the second line of each character etc...

So, to print 98, instead of:

```
print " __ "   # 9, row 1
print "|__|"   # 9, row 2
print "   |"   # 9, row 3

print " __ "   # 8, row 1
print "|__|"   # 8, row 2
print "|__|"   # 8, row 3
```

You have to:

```
print " __ ",  # 9, row 1
print " __ ",  # 8, row 1
print

print "|__|",  # 9, row 2
print "|__|",  # 8, row 2
print

print "   |",  # 9, row 3
print "|__|",  # 8, row 3
print
```

Note that I added a comma after each line, so it does not make a line break. Then I added a line break (empty print) once for each line, after all characters.

Now, to print any number, you'll have to go through all characters three times: once for each line...

Comment: So what would be a better way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

funny exercice :)

following the comments of @zvone perhaps something like this:

```
def zero():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += ["|  |"]
    chars += ["|__|"]
    return chars

def one():
    chars  = ["    "]
    chars += ["   |"]
    chars += ["   |"]
    return chars

def two():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += [" __|"]
    chars += ["|__ "]
    return chars

def three():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += [" __|"]
    chars += [" __|"]
    return chars

def four():
    chars  = ["   "]
    chars += ["|_|"]
    chars += ["  |"]
    return chars

def five():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += ["|__ "]
    chars += [" __|"]
    return chars

def six():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += ["|__ "]
    chars += ["|__|"]
    return chars

def seven():
    chars  = ["  __ "]
    chars += ["    |"]
    chars += ["    |"]
    return chars

def eight():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += ["|__|"]
    chars += ["|__|"]
    return chars

def nine():
    chars  = [" __ "]
    chars += ["|__|"]
    chars += ["   |"]
    return chars

numbers = {'0': zero,
           '1': one,
           '2': two,
           '3': three,
           '4': four,
           '5': five,
           '6': six,
           '7': seven,
           '8': eight,
           '9': nine}

def print_lcd(a):
    for line in zip(*[numbers[num]() for num in a]):
        print ' '.join(line)
    else:
        print "Number not entered"

x = raw_input("Type the number you would like printed: ")
a = list(x)
print_lcd(a)
```